# pbs torque configuration settings

Tags: torque

For a pbs torque 6.1.2 scheduler where is the configuration saved?  I've been searching and I'm just not finding it anywhere.

For instance I've changed the max walltime to 120 hours using qmgr.  Where does the system save that setting so it remains after a restart of the scheduler or a reboot?